# How to create a parallel linear computation in one layer with TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have inputs with size [batch_size, height, width]. Here I want to do several different parallel linear transformation in one layer, i.e.,

```
x = tensor([batch_size, height, width])
y = [W1*x, W2*x, W3*x,...,Wn*x]
```

I noticed that there are `fully_connected` and `layer.dense` in TensorFlow but they can only do one linear transformation at a time? Can I use them to do parallel linear transformation?

I'm new to TensorFlow, sorry if this question is kinda stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking advantage of broadcasting:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size, height, width = 5, 4, 3
n = 2

x = tf.random_uniform((batch_size, height, width))
W = tf.random_uniform((n,))

y = tf.multiply(tf.reshape(W, (n, 1, 1, 1)), tf.expand_dims(x, 0))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    y = sess.run(y)
    print(y.shape)
    # (2, 5, 4, 3)
```

Comment: Sorry, my description was not clear before. Here I want `W` to be the same size as `x` and `y` should be a 1D vector. Can I do that with broadcasting?

Comment: What do you mean by `Wi*x` then, if it has to return a scalar value? What kind of operation do you need between these 2 tensors?

Comment: Oh, it's dot production. I think I've figured out how to do this following your code. Thanks anyway!